# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'constructor') Etherjs error

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to interact with a deployed contract at Sepolia in a hardhat test. Here's how I do it:

```
const provider= new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY);
    
const contract = await ethers.Contract("0xFd57b4ddBf88a4e07fF4e34C487b99af2Fe82a05",BnMABI,provider);
```

I still don't know why I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'constructor')
```

I have seen a lot of posts on Google and they do the same to interact with smart contracts from frontend. I don't know why it's not working in hardhat.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Just change in the second line to `const contract = new ethers.Contract` so you'll call class constructor.

And no need in await on second line as constructor in synchronous